# Do I need to buy additional devices to make the best of SATA express?

Tags: sata

The motherboard I am looking at is http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813130892, which supports SATAe. This is a new term to me. I've done some research and am only able to understand that SATAe can make the R/W of my SSD faster. In the video that I watched about SATAe, a PCI card is introduced, I am not sure what it has to do with SATAe, and wonder whethere I need to buy additional gears to make the best of SATAe. Or, does the MB has a SATAe port where I can simply connect my SSD to it?(Assume my SSD support SATAe)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use SATA Express, you would need to use a SSD that supports SATA Express. I'm currently not aware of a SSD that supports SATA Express. It does have a much higher theoretical speed than SATA and would be good for SSDs. I would still recommend a SSD through PCIe or M.2 (which uses PCIe internally).